# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have been working on keras yolov3 model for object detection. This error keeps showing up. 
Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'
```

I don't know what to do. I have tried replacing "import keras.module.module" to "tensorflow.keras.module.module". But still it doesn't work.

The full output code:

```
runfile('G:/Traffic Violation Detection/object_detection.py', wdir='G:/Traffic Violation Detection')
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-0715decb6662>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('G:/Traffic Violation Detection/object_detection.py', wdir='G:/Traffic Violation Detection')

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "G:/Traffic Violation Detection/object_detection.py", line 6, in <module>
    from keras.layers.merge import add, concatenate

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *

  File "C:\Users\HP-NPC\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_platform\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 54, in <module>
    get_graph = tf_keras_backend.get_graph

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'
```

My imports:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU, ZeroPadding2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.merge import add, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import struct
import cv2
import imageio
```

For full code please visit: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oVR7swBqjfqxR50C3xt89w1vGEAaTFcK#scrollTo=rpSn_HsUHbGF

Comment: show some code you wrote

Comment: Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added the link to my codes. @AccLok

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project "YOLOv3 model for object detection" has some issues with versions. I had the same issue and I used tensorflow 1.14.0 and keras 2.2.0.

Just overwrite the specific versions. Write in the command line.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
pip install keras==2.2.0
```

Comment: I am loathing TensorFlow for this. Nothing works with a single version. Even with minor version change, big things break.

Comment: Totally agreed. Tensorflow is widely used. It should have been compatible in terms of version change. @PrameshBajracharya

Answer (score 4):

I installed `tensorflow v1.14.0` using `pip install tensorflow==1.14.0` and `keras v2.2.0` using `pip install keras==2.2.0` and it should definitely work.